# Equivalent expression for “No ifs, ands or buts” in Portuguese

Tags: expressões, expressões-idiomáticas

In English the expression **"No ifs ands or buts"** meaning. This expression is used when we want to make it clear to the other person that we will not accept any excuses.

Does there exist any equivalent expression in Portuguese?

---

Em Inglês usamos a expressão **"No ifs, ands or buts"**. Essa expressão é usada quando desejamos deixar claro à outra pessoa que não aceitaremos nenhuma desculpa.

Existe alguma expressão equivalente em Português?

Comment: No Brasil temos mais de uma alternativa para isso, mas talvez a mais comum seja *não tem conversa*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em Portugal usamos uma expressão:

> Sem se nem meio se

ou

> Nem se, nem meio se

*neither 'if' nor half 'if'*

---

Outra muito usada também é:

> Sem mas nem meio mas

ou

> Nem mas, nem meio mas

*neither 'but' nor half 'but'*

---

Comment: Em vez dos 'Sem' sempre ouvi 'Nem'. O Google parece concordar comigo. Além disto penso que falta uma vírgula antes de cada 'nem'.

Comment: @GitGud as duas formas com "nem" e com "sem" são usadas.

Comment: "Nem mas nem meio mas" foi a que mais ouvi. Parece a expressão mais equivalente.

Comment: @JorgeB. Em Portugal é habitual usar "Não enrola"?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não usamos.

Answer (score 3):

I found this expressions (Eu encontrei estas expressões):

> - Sem desculpas
> - Não me venha com desculpas
> - Sem mas

Source: http://inglesnapontadalingua.com.br/2015/01/o-que-significa-no-ifs-ands-buts.html

Or:

> - Nem mas, nem menos

In Brazil is used (but it can be used in other situations):

> - Sem enrolação (ou *Não enrola*)